# Undefined index when submitting an upload image

Tags: php

I have a funny one here - I am running a local install of MAMP on both my Mac and a windows laptop. The code for the image upload works fine using the exact same files on my local version of windows, but when running the same thing on my Mac I get the error undefined index on line...

The error is referring to `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];`

```
$filename = date("Y-m-d_H-i-s").'-'.$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$dest = '../uploads/';

// Check for errors
if($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] > 0){
    die('An error ocurred when uploading.');
}

if(!getimagesize($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'])){
    die('Please ensure you are uploading an image.');
}

// Check filetype
/*
if($_FILES['file_upload']['type'] != 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image, jpeg'){
    die('Unsupported filetype uploaded.');
}
*/

// Check filesize
if($_FILES['file_upload']['size'] > 500000){
    die('File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.');
}

// Check if the file exists
if(file_exists('../uploads/' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'])){
    die('File with that name already exists.');
}

// Upload file
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], $dest . $filename)){
    die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
}
```

Very odd case indeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I figured it out I was using `[image]` where I should have been using `[file_upload]`